# protected router with react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this Protected route is works well for profile page. but i want to make a protected route for multiple page. in my project , i want to implement protected route for 'user profile update page', "update password" and 'order details  page'  but i can not implement this.

[image: this is user profile page on my project]

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (loading) return null;
  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import React from 'react';
import Service from './components/Service/Service'
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import About from './components/About/About'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Login from './components/User/Login';
import Cart from './components/Cart/Cart';
import ProductDetails from './components/Product/ProductDetails';
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop/ScrollToTop';
import Signup from './components/User/Signup';
import Shipping from './components/Cart/Shipping';
import Profile from './components/User/Profile';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './Actions/userAction';
import UserOptions from './components/Header/UserOptions';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/Route/ProtectedRoute';
import UpdateProfile from './components/User/UpdateProfile'
import ForgotPassword from './components/User/ForgotPassword';
import ResetPassword from './components/User/ResetPassword';
import MyOrders from './components/Order/MyOrders';

function App() {

  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Header />
      {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/about' element={<About />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/service' element={<Service />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/signup' element={<Signup />} ></Route>


        <Route path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
        </Route>


        <Route exact path="/password/forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route exact path="/password/reset/:token" element={<ResetPassword />} />
        <Route exact path='/cart' element={<Cart />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails />} ></Route>
        <Route exact path='/shipping' element={<Shipping />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i tried this but it didn't work

```
<Route path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
    <Route path="/account" element={<Profile/>} /> 
    <Route path="me/update" element={<UpdateProfile/>} />
    <Route path="/orders" element={<MyOrders/>} /> 
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead:

`<Route path="/account" element={<ProtectedRoute><Profile/></ProtectedRoute>}></Route>`

`<Route path="me/update" element={<ProtectedRoute><UpdateProfile/></ProtectedRoute>}></Route>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping each element with ProtectedRoute, do it at once

Use like this:

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
    <Route path="/account" element={<Profile/>} /> 
    <Route path="me/update" element={<UpdateProfile/>} />
    <Route path="/orders" element={<MyOrders/>} /> 
</Route>
```